# How can I get inside event_Click from instance of UserControl that created dynamicly from Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, onclick

**I have UserControl:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="wControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestProjectSite.wControl1" %>
<asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Button12" onclick="Button12_Click" OnClientClick="true" />
```

C#:

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button12.Text = Name;

        }

        protected void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //...
            //The problem is here... it doesn't get inside...
        }
```

And **Page .ASPX:**

```
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="500" Height="34" runat="server" 
        Font-Size="22px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="32" Text="חפש..." 
        OnClick="Button2_Click" Font-Size="20px" />
</p>
<P>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhItems" runat="server" >
</P>
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                 
            Func(TextBox1.Text);
        }

        public void Func(string text)
        {                      
                    wControl1 eControl = (wControl1)Page.LoadControl("wControl1.ascx");
                    eControl.Name = text;

                    plhItems.Controls.Add(eControl);
        }
```

The problem is in the event of Button12_Click.

the instance of the control is created when i press the button(Button2).
but when i press again in the button of UserControl(wControl) he doesn't go to codeBehind eventClick....   only if I use the create of the userControl in Page_Load event it will be OK.. but I want it from the event of Button2...

What can I do??

THANKS..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to understand why your Button12_Click event is not being called after you create it during Button2's click?

The reason is that when the post back occurs for the Button12 click, the button does not exist in the control heirarchy anymore so the event handler does not get hooked up and therfore will not fire.

You have several options:

1. Always have button12 on the page but only make it visible when button2 is clicked.
2. Add Button12 as you are but store off in either viewstate or session that the button as been created and then make sure to recreate the button during the load event.

Comment: ok I think that the number 2 more good... but there is more options to do?   its good to save in viewstate?

Comment: I could not yet fix the problem ...
Maybe you have some sample code to show me (by the code presented here)?